# Gradle mavenDeployer fails while creating directory at wrong place

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a build.gradle script with following section to upload artifacts to a private release Maven repo:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "/opt/maven_repo/private-release") {
                pom.artifactId = archive
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I run the build on a unix machine and the user has write access to the directory /opt/maven_repo/private-release. However, the task fails with following output:

```
:uploadArchives
Uploading: company-name/artifact-name/relX.N/artifact-name-relX.N.jar to repository remote at /opt/maven_repo/private-release
Specified destination directory cannot be created: /company-name/artifact-name/relX.N
:uploadArchives FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > Error deploying artifact 'artifact-name:jar': Error deploying artifact: Specified destination directory cannot be created: /company-name/artifact-name/relX.N
```

P.S.: the artifact is actually placed in ~/.m2/repository and I have a feeling it tries to create the directory in the root catalog instead of the specified repository directory

Comment: Try with a `file:///` URL. Also try to create the `/opt/maven_repo/private-release` direcory beforehand. The fact that the artifact is also placed in the local Maven repository is a known limitation that may have been fixed by now.

Comment: I'm actually ashamed of myself that I stopped on just file://. file:/// does the trick. Thanks!